# FCC Guidelines for Radar

Tags: legal, fcc, microwave

I'm working on some research for a project of mine. The project requires the use of millimeter wave radar. I am having a very hard time figuring out what the FCC's regulations on frequencies and broadcast power are. Google seemingly only leads me to vague commercial licenses. Could someone help me find some specifics?

Comment: What frequencies? (Please edit your question to include this.)

Comment: My starting place would be Part 97 (http://www.arrl.org/part-97-text) starting with 97.301 that shows what amateur bands are available, then later sections describing power and other limitations.

Comment: As Mike mentioned, please edit your Q to include specific frequencies or frequency bands. Also include power and the nature of the antenna for xmit including any gain. And if this will be for mobile, portable, or fixed use.

Answer (score 2):

I did some quick googling and landed on [47 CFR § 15.255 - Operation within the band 57-71 GHz](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/47/15.255) at the excellent Cornell Law Legal Information Institute.

I've quoted some excerpts that I think you'll find relevant:

> § 15.255 Operation within the band 57-71 GHz.
>
> **(a)(2)**... employed for fixed operation, or used as short-range devices for interactive motion sensing...
>
> **(c)** Within the 57-71 GHz band, emission levels shall not exceed the following equivalent isotropically radiated power (EIRP):
> **(2)** For **fixed** field disturbance sensors that occupy 500 MHz or less of bandwidth and that are contained wholly within the frequency band 61.0-61.5 GHz, the average power of any emission, measured during the transmit interval, shall not exceed 40 dBm, and the peak power of any emission shall not exceed 43 dBm. In addition, the average power of any emission outside of the 61.0-61.5 GHz band, measured during the transmit interval, but still within the 57-71 GHz band, shall not exceed 10 dBm, and the peak power of any emission shall not exceed 13 dBm.
> **(3)** For fixed field disturbance sensors other than those operating under the provisions of paragraph (c)(2) of this section, and short-range devices for interactive motion sensing, the peak transmitter conducted output power shall not exceed −10 dBm and the peak EIRP level shall not exceed 10 dBm.
> **(4)** The peak power shall be measured with an RF detector that has a detection bandwidth that encompasses the 57-71 GHz band and has a video bandwidth of at least 10 MHz. The average emission levels shall be measured over the actual time period during which transmission occurs.

And that page also has more requirements re allowable power, measurement methodology, as well as spurious emission suppression.

If this isn't responsive to your question, please consider updating your question to include additional information such as specific frequencies or bands, mobile/portable/fixed use case, and xmit power.

Happy radioing!